# How to select an object by script - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, selection

I am a beginner in Unity and I am currently making a simple game. I have a problem where I need to select an object automatically by script so I can click outside of it without clicking on it in the screen.

What I want to do is when I click the object another object or panel will show and it will be automatically be selected by script so I can click outside the panel and it will close or will `setActive` to `false`. I tried the `Select()` and it is not working for me. The two objects are originally an `Image` but I added a `Button` component so it can be selectable.

This is the script for the object that will show the Panel:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ShowPhone : MonoBehaviour, ISelectHandler
{
    [SerializeField] Button phonePanel;

    public void OnSelect(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        phonePanel.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    }
}
```

This is the script for the panel where I want to click outside to close it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class HidePhoen : MonoBehaviour, IDeselectHandler
{
    public Button phone;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        phone.Select();
    }

    public void OnDeselect(BaseEventData data)
    {
        Debug.Log("The Object will be setActive false when clicked outside the object");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [`EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject.html)

```
EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(yourTargetGameObject);
```

Note though:  Your panel would automatically be closed even if clicking any UI element within it (like e.g. InputField etc)

---

You can checkout the [`TMP_Dropdown`](https://github.com/AppertaFoundation/IXN_IBM_MIND/blob/8aa21d78bfe90e6feeab3cce6256e7fbb6036734/Whack-A-Mole/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro%402.0.0/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_Dropdown.cs#L847) source code and the way they implemented a "UI Blocker" which basically is an overlay over the entire screen except the drop-down popup and closes the pop-up when clicked on.

you could either replicate this or have a simpler version with a fully transparent background button behind your panel with `onClick` for closing the panel.

As alternative you could check [`RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint.html)

Comment: The `EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject` seems to be working, but it returns an error `Attempting to select PhonePanel (UnityEngine.GameObject)while already selecting an object.` How can I solve this error?

Comment: What I did is I replaced the `Select()` to `SelectedGameObject` in the `OnEnable` method. And it returns that error. Is there something wrong with the placement of the code?

Comment: When I put null to the SetSelectedGameObject so it can reset what is being selected, it returns the error `Attempting to select while already selecting an object.`. I checked the Scripting, but it should send OnDeselect on the previous selected object but it is not working.

Comment: I just gone with the fully transparent background button. I can't make the `SelectedGameObject` work.

Comment: I guess this happens because the `OnEnable` already happens as reaction to a button click and therefore a `Select` of that button in the same frame .. tbh no sure though how to overcome this except for delaying the select by a frame